# Eclipse Data Source Explorer and MS-Access

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I can't see any of my schemas when I try to use Eclipse data source explorer. It's not a problem with JDBC connection because I can connect and execute SQL statements. It's just that the tables don't appear. How do I make them to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely you cannot. Access has a very limited ODBC support (as I suppose you are using the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver). You don't have many options. You could purchase a JDBC driver with more functionality (expensive), and if your Access is 97 or 2000, the QuantumDB Eclipse plugin has a trick to get metadata information from these versions, by exploring the system tables. Perhaps you can find other plugins that manage that for more recent versions, but otherwise, you are stuck.